# How To attach an image and an audio file to an email in android?

Tags: android

I am New To Android,My Requirement is to Attach an ImageFile and an AudioFile to an E-mail in android?
can anyone help me..?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't attach more than 1 file using the email send intent (don't really know why).

Your options are:

- Zip your files and attach (1 file) OR,
- Send an email programmatically without using an Intent.

[http://jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_(Programmatically)](http://jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29)
[http://jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android](http://jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    for (String file : filePaths)
    {
        File fileIn = new File(file);
        Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
        uris.add(u);
    }
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris); // intent is your
```